# How to avoid http request with 304 response?

Tags: javascript, http, tomcat, browser-cache

I am using tomcat8, and I have a very large javascript file in our project. By default, the browser and tomcat will use Last-Modified,ETag to determinate if the javascript file need to be transferred or use the cached one.

But since the javascript file rarely update, So I hope the browser can use local cached one and do not ask server if the file was modifed since in this way the http request is still needed. I think it's a waste.

Then I used below expiresfilter to send expires head to browser.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>ExpiresFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.ExpiresFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>ExpiresByType image</param-name>
        <param-value>access plus 10 minutes</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>ExpiresByType text/css</param-name>
        <param-value>access plus 10 minutes</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>ExpiresByType application/javascript</param-name>
        <param-value>access plus 10 minutes</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ExpiresFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

But it still does not work. The http request was still sent and http response 304 was received.

How can I avoid this unnecessary request? And if I implement it, how can I ask browser to get the new script If I really updated it about 3 months a time ?

Comment: do you understand what a 304 response is? and what it means when a browser gets this response? [read this](https://httpstatuses.com/304)

Comment: 304 means the sever say file was not changed and browser still use cached one. But the browser and server still create a tcp connection. how to avoid it?

Comment: how will the browser know when the file has changed if it doesn't "ask"? A browser uses a cached copy as a result of a 304 response - is your bandwidth so limited that a tiny request like that is going to cause issues?